# linked list access violation writing location

Tags: c++, pointers, linked-list

I'm writing a program doing LSD radix sort with SSN. The program will parse the number into 3 digits and do 3 passes. Each pass I store the number into corresponding array element bucket[]; if there's a duplicate, I create a linked list in that location and store the duplicated one behind the one that's already there. The code breaks when I try to insert in the end of the linked list.

EDIT new error message

```
class node
{ 
public:
    node(int n, node *p){data=n;next=p;}
    int data;
    node *next;
};


void genData(int *dta, int n) 
{

for(int i=0; i < n; i++)// generate the social security numbers at random
    dta[i] =  rand()%889 + 111 + 1000*(rand()%889 + 111) + 1000000*                            (rand()%889 + 111);
 }

int radixSort(int *dta, int n, int *out)
{ 
// the dta array contains the data to be sorted.
// n is the number of data items in the array
// out is the array to put the sorted data

node *bucket[1000]; // declare an array of 1000 linked lists (head pointers)
int count = 0; // use this to count the instructions to graph the big-o
for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)out[i] = dta[i]; 

for (int pass = 0; pass < 3; pass++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < 1000; j++){
        bucket[j] = NULL;
    }
    delete bucket;
    delete[]bucket;

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++){
        int index=0;
        switch (pass)
        {
        case 0:
            index = out[i] % 1000;
        case 1:
            index = (out[i]/1000) % 1000;
        case 2:
            index = out[i] / 1000000;
        };
        if (bucket[index] = NULL){
            bucket[index] = new node(out[i], NULL);
        }
        else{

            node *cur=bucket[index];
            while (cur->next!= nullptr){   //****access violation reading location
                cur = cur->next;
            }
            node *ptr = new node(out[i], NULL);
            cur->next = ptr;
        }
    }
    int idx = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++){
        if (bucket[i] == NULL) continue;
        else{
            out[idx] = bucket[i]->data;
            idx++;
            count++;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `cur` is null after `while(cur!=NULL)`

Answer (score 0):

Theres a number of problems in your code:

1. In your switch-statement you have lines like `index == out[i] % 1000;`Those do a comparison and i doubt this is what you want. Assignments use single =
2. Your initialization `for (int j = 0; j < 1000; j++){bucket[j] = NULL;}` does not check if theres already a pointer in it - this will cause memory leaks after the first pass. Remember: Every `new` needs a `delete`.
3. And thats what is probably breaking your code: `while (cur!= NULL){cur = cur->next;}` exits the while-loop once cur is the nullptr - which means trying to dereference it 2 lines later is trying to dereference the nullptr and a bad idea. What you probably want to check in order to get your last element is `while(cur->next != nullptr)

And just as a note: if your compiler supports `nullptr` its a good idea to use it, even if you might need to enable C++11 via appropriate flags.

Comment: I was using `while (cur->next !=nullptr)` before, but it gave me a access violation reading location error

Comment: is your `next` properly initialized in the `node`-constructor?

Comment: yes `class node{int data; node* next; node(int n, node *p){data=n; next=p;} }`

Comment: and did you use it with the other corrections? because if i don`t see the actual code i can only speculate what else might have been wrong at that time.. In the code posted above you are definitely dereferencing the nullptr

Comment: yes I fixed them. I just posted the edited version. Could you take a look? It seems like the `delete` is triggering a break point also.